# How to use Vlookup in VBa?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

This is a code I wrote to use Vlookup in Vba, but I keep getting

Run-time error 1004
Unable to get the Vlookup property of the Worksheet function class

```
If WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ListBox1.Selected(0), Range("B4:C7"), 2, False)) = True Then
'Create row
 Range("EndlineFM").Select
   Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
 'Initialise Detail and montant of new row
   Range("TotalF").Offset(-1, 0) = FraisM.ListBox1.Selected(0)
Range("TotalF").Offset(-1, 1) = CSng(FraisM.Chiffremontant)
```

How can I fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your comment... Is the problem taken care of? Or do you mean you should edit what you wrote? If the first, please delete; if the second you can use the [edit] link below a question to change it or add new information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` will always raise a run-time error if there's no match found - you cannot handle that using `IsNA()`

You can do it like this without the `WorksheetFunction`:

```
Dim m    

m = Application.VLookup(ListBox1.Selected(0), Range("B4:C7"), 2, False))

If IsError(m) Then
    'Create row
     Range("EndlineFM").Insert Shift:=xlDown
     'Initialise Detail and montant of new row
     Range("TotalF").Offset(-1, 0) = FraisM.ListBox1.Selected(0)
     Range("TotalF").Offset(-1, 1) = CSng(FraisM.Chiffremontant)
     'etc
```

Comment: Thanks, i should use the error handling my answer. However using `ListBox1.Selected(0)` is boolean and throwing error 1004. Please guide.I am working from module as it is not mentioned clearly.

Comment: If you have to use error handling then here's a good reference: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm

Comment: I am concerned about why `ListBox1.Selected(0)` is causing error whether it is true or false. I had to use `FraisM.ListBox1.List(FraisM.ListBox1.ListIndex)`

Answer (score 0):

It is working like this

```
Dim Txt As Variant
On Error Resume Next 
Txt = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FraisM.ListBox1.List(FraisM.ListBox1.ListIndex), Range("B4:C7"), 2, False)
             If Err.Number <> 0 Then
             MsgBox " Not found" ''optional, no need to do anything
             Err.Clear
             Exit Sub   ' Or may use Goto label
             End If
     On Error GoTo 0
    'Create row
     Range("EndlineFM").Select
     Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    'Initialise Detail and montant of new row
     Range("TotalF").Offset(-1, 0) = Txt
```

I have taken `FraisM` as Userform Name and assumed code running from Module. If You are using `Msform.ListBox` on worksheet the may try

```
Dim MyLB  As Object
Set MyLB = Sheet1.Shapes("List Box 1")
Txt = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(MyLB.ControlFormat.List(MyLB.ControlFormat.ListIndex), Range("B4:C7"), 2, False)
```